# Python - How to extract chunked elements?

Tags: python, nltk

I am new to python and I'm giving nltk a shot. I came across the following:

```
namedEnt = nltk.ne_chunk(tagged)
```

Where tagged is

```
tagged = nltk.pos_tag(words)
```

and words are token's of a sentence.
I would like to remove the stop words of `namedEnt`. I was able to first remove the stop words from the tokens and then chunk, but was not able to chunk and then remove the stop words.
Is it possible ? If so, how could I do this ?
Eg: Sentence- "get me todays menu." is tagged into

> ('get', 'VB')
>   ('me', 'PRP')
>   ('todays', 'JJ')
>   ('menu', 'NN')
>   ('.', '.')

and I would like to get

> ('get','VB')('todays','JJ')('menu','NN')('.','.')

Comment: You can simply use various packages to remove stopwords and then do chunking. Have you tried this?

Comment: Tell us what have you done so far.

Comment: @RahulAgarwal I want to first chunk the sentence and then remove the stop words present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I get what you want (if you feed filtered from the example below to nltk.ne_chunk, it probably results in incorrect output because ne_chunk expects a grammatical sentence I guess), but your input output can be achieved in the following way:

```
>>> import nltk
>>> words = ['Get', 'me', 'todays', 'menu', '.']
>>> tagged = nltk.pos_tag(words)
>>> tagged
[('Get', 'NN'), ('me', 'PRP'), ('todays', 'VBZ'), ('menu', 'NN'), ('.', '.')]
>>> filtered = [t for t in tagged if not t[0] in set(nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('english'))]
>>> filtered
[('Get', 'NN'), ('todays', 'VBZ'), ('menu', 'NN'), ('.', '.')]
```

Again, not sure how useful this actually is. NamedEnt in your example returns a tree structure, so you'd have to traverse this tree to extract whichever you are interested in, which probably means skipping over stopwords anyway...

Comment: Yup, it works. I tried extracting words via traversal which is also another solution, like you specified. Thank you.